# Whats the xpath for this code on the website flipkart.com for the search box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Can someone tell me what the xpath is for this code for a search box on flipkart.com:
I have tried `x$('//input[contains='Search for products, brands and more']')`

I am trying to select this element:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="LM6RPg" title="Search for products, brands and more" name="q" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for products, brands and more">
```

Comment: Your question does not provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please elaborate I am new to this forum

Comment: In your case a [mcve] should provide a sample XML on which the XPath can operate. This _verifiable_ example is necessary to ensure that everybody operates on the same dataset and receives the same errors (or confirmations). It will most likely be a subset of the whole XML/HTML.

Comment: So you want more code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you go on www.flipcart.com and inspect rather than me copying all the code in this question?

Comment: No. We do not go to another site to figure out what you're asking. You need to spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve], before you start posting here. (Since you don't seem to understand, [tour] is a clickable link that you should follow, as is [help] and [mcve]. Click them and read the pages you end up on.)

Answer (score 0):

Your current XPath is evaluating whether there is an `input` element that has a `contains` element who's value is equal to "Search for products, brands and more".

Adjust the predicate in your XPath to evaluate whether the `@title` attribute value is equal to that string:

```
x$('//input[@title='Search for products, brands and more']')
```